# Blurry text on high density screens

Tags: android

My application which I built for 1.5, shows text blurry on high density screen of HTC Desire and the like. Here is a close up screen shot from my application (bad.png) and a better example (good.png)

[alt text http://taypo.com/bad.png](http://taypo.com/bad.png) [alt text http://taypo.com/good.png](http://taypo.com/good.png)

Yes, I am building a soft keyboard. And the text is drawn with `canvas.drawText`. All the discussions I found online is about image resizing issues.

Comment: Android 1.5 doesn't support multiple screen resolutions, so I don't know if you'll be able to solve this

Comment: My problem happens on Android 2.1. Do you mean I should be building against 2.1 SDK to solve the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read this [guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Basically, if you want support 1.5 devices you should  build your project 
against SDK >= 1.6 with the minSdkVersion setted to 3:

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="3"
        android:targetSdkVersion="4"
    />
```

On this way you will be able to have differents drawable resources for differents
screen size/density without breaking the compability with Android 1.5 
which assumes all screens are "mdpi".
obviously you can't use any api released after sdk version 3

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is still strange that text drawing is also effected with this difference.